# Assigning elevation to point shapefile based on point file using ArcGIS Desktop

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point, geoprocessing-framework

Goal:

Extract elevation data (Data B) based on given point file locations (Data A).

Current problem:

I have several sets of xyz data for large areas with a resolution of 1m. I converted those to Point Data (Data B). When I apply the approach of (1) Point to Raster, (2) Extract Points from Raster it requires a lot of time for the geoprocessing. That's why I'm searching for a way to bypass the rasterprocessing.

I was wondering if its possible to just assign the elevation of the closest points (Data B) to my target points (Data A)?

I found some similar questions, but none of them discussing which method is the fastest and most of them were handled in QGIS, while I work with ArcGIS 10.7:

- [Assigning a nearest polygon to a point](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/59487/assigning-a-nearest-polygon-to-a-point)
- [Joining attributes from nearest point in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/11377/joining-attributes-from-nearest-point-in-qgis)
- [Assigning Elevation data from one point shapefile to another point shapefile in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/268886/assigning-elevation-data-from-one-point-shapefile-to-another-point-shapefile-in)

Comment: So you have a raster with elevation? Do you need Data A to be z-enabled or do you just need the elevation field populated? This is not quite clear.

Comment: Hi @danak. No I dont have an elevation raster. What I have are point information with elevations

Comment: Spatial Join tool might help